# Can not to import EXcel file to Cassandra with SSIS--Invalid null value in condition for column

Tags: excel, import, ssis, cassandra, odbc

otally i want to import a simple excel file with one coloumn and one row to cassandra in other words,  i want to test whether we can import from ssis windwos to cassandra that is installed to virtual machine linux or not ?
for testing this target i do following steps :

i install cassandra in virtual machine **ubunto** and  it has ip 10.20.14.99 alone and in my host machine which is windows 8 i install ssis and it has ip in range of virtual machine. bridge the adapters so they connect successfully to each other the host and virtual machine.

in cassandra.yaml which is the config file of cassandra i change the rpc_address to the ip of virtual machine instead of localhost. the reason is when i want to remotely call cassandra from ssis i should set this config on my cassandra.
furthermore i install odbc driver 64 bit and32 bit on windows 8 and define my dsn correctl in order to connect the ssis to my cassandra

i define a table in cassandra with one coloumn named id which this column is primary key also my table does not have any record. also i create a simple excel file with one coloumn id with two row. i want to insert this two rows to cassandra

i successfully can connect to cassandra from ssis and preview our resultset in cassandra.  since i dont have any record in cassandra there is no result set. my cassandra is empty.

my excel file with xls format has two rows.

when i execute my package the data flow like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km9EU.png)
the reason for that i put conditional split is that to check whether the id column is null or not. the flow indicate that two rows are not null from point of view of id column and redirect successfully to odbc destination for insert operation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFyUl.png)

**the error i face with it :**

Error: 0x384 at insert, ODBC Destination [41]: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. SQLExecute returned error while inserting row 1
Error: 0x384 at insert, ODBC Destination [41]: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY000'. Native Error Code: 10. [DataStax][CassandraODBC] (10) Error while executing a query in Cassandra: [33563136] : **Invalid null value in condition for column id**
Error: 0xC0047022 at insert, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ODBC Destination" (41) failed with error code 0x80004005 while processing input "ODBC Destination Input" (52). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure

i dont know how to handle this error althogh i handle null column in conditional split
i get confused plz help me in other post i log my caasandra log after start the package