# import error from excel source to cassandra destination with odbc driver in ssis

Tags: import, ssis, cassandra, remote-access

I describe my problem in this thread 
[Can not to import EXcel file to Cassandra with SSIS--Invalid null value in condition for column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403706/can-not-to-import-excel-file-to-cassandra-with-ssis-invalid-null-value-in-condi)

Can anybody there help me to import a simple excel file to cassandra? I should say that export to excel file from remote cassandra is not problem and is done with out any problem.

When I have ssis and caasandra database on local host I don't have any problem to import and export data to cassanra but when I put my cassandra in virtual machine and ssis in host machine I successfully can connect ssis to cassandra and fetch result set from cassandra but can not insert data from excel to cassandra. 
The error is that when try to open connectivity to odbc driver and insert row think that primary column is null but before that I send my row for writing I check the null values with conditional split.

Maybe this problem is related to my odbc driver?

My Windows is 8 and 64 bit -- ssis is 32 bit and run it in mode 32
 ssis only see odbc driver 32 bit and I choose 32 bit odbc driver that I define in  odbc driver administer.

Please help me I want to decide whether I choose cassandra as a solution or not and this import is really important for me.

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using, and which ODBC driver?

Comment: my cassandra version is 2.2.5 and and use DataStaxCassandraODBC32 the reason that i use odbc 32 bit is that ssis is 32 bit and when browsing the dsn only 32 dsn is visible for choosing. we can define 32 and 64 bit dsn in odbc driver administer depend on driver type and version but only dsn 32 is visible in ssis. visual studio 2013 and separately install ssdt for visual studio 2013

Comment: OK, great. Are you able to copy the exact error message that you're getting from SSIS?

Comment: Error: 0x384 at insert, ODBC Destination Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. SQLExecute returned error while inserting row 1 Error: 0x384 at insert, ODBC Destination : Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY000'. Native Error Code: 10. [DataStax][CassandraODBC] Error while executing a query in Cassandra -Invalid null value in condition for column id Error: 0xC0047022 at insert, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on "ODBC Destination" failed with error code 0x80004005 while processing input "ODBC Destination Input

Comment: Something that may be causing this issue is that the column is stated as non-nullable, and a null value is making it through, or something similar. Would you be able to generate a driver manager and driver log? The driver logging instructions should be in the install guide, DM logging instructions are here: http://www.simba.com/blog/odbc-troubleshooting-tracing/

Comment: i enable logging on my driver manager and see log actually overllay can not understand what it logs but main review on this log show all sql query is sucess full only one place i see this DtsDebugHost    4568-5350 EXIT  SQLFetch  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
  HSTMT               0x0AE12F88

Comment: here is my  total log file of driver manager  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04980249375207039300

Comment: Could you please also provide the driver log? The driver manager log shows the relevant column reported as being nullable.

Comment: thanks for your attention log file of driver manager is different from driver log if yes where i can find the driver log ?   in link that you send for me i catch the log file of driver manager .

Comment: i upload the log file of driver manager in  s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04980249375207039300  link

Comment: thanks alot my problem is for version of visual studio i swith to 2015 and ssdt 2014 and my problem is solved

Comment: Just to clarify, your problem is solved when you switched to VS2015 and SSDT2014? To answer your question about driver logging, see http://cdn.simba.com/products/Cassandra/doc/Simba_Cassandra_ODBC_InstallGuide.pdf on page 14.